# How do I create a health score calculator in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a task to create a simple calculator that checks your health risk score,
In general, it looks like this:
ex. 
If you have BMI of more than 18 but less than 23, you get 0 points, if over 23, you get 2 points. If you walk more than 8000 steps/week you get -1 points, if less than 4000 than 2 points. So the more points you gain, the higher is your risk score, which means you get a lower grade.

I know its simple, but I am having an issue with calculating and saving variables so that I could convert them to score.

here is how I am trying to do it, I get inputted value:

```
  var calcSteps = parseFloat(document.getElementById('steps').value);
```

then I check how many points this value is worth:

```
var steps = document.Form.steps.value
if (steps >= 8000) {
   document.form.steps_meaning.value = -1
}
if (steps >= 6000 && steps < 8000) {
   document.form.steps_meaning.value = -0.5
}
if (steps >= 4000 && steps < 6000) {
   document.form.steps_meaning.value = 0
}
if (steps >= 2000 && steps < 4000) {
   document.form.steps_meaning.value = 1
}
if (steps >= 1000 && steps < 2000) {
   document.form.steps_meaning.value = 1.5
}
if (steps >= 0 && steps < 1000) {
   document.form.steps_meaning.value = 2
}
if (steps = "") {
   document.form.steps_meaning.value = "error"
} else {
   alert("")
}
```

now I need to store this data somewhere,so I can sum up all points.
Please let me know how I could sum up all points, or if there is any example of a similar code.

Comment: just store it in a javascript variable... if you need to store it more permanently then you'll need to send it to a server and store it in a DB through server-side code but that's a very broad scope to cover in an answer here...

Comment: You might need to take a step back and make the question a bit more clear, as it's a bit confusing. You've outlined that you're storing the input value in a variable called `calcSteps`, but in your second code block you seem to be attempting to get the same value again and place it in a separate variable called `steps`.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an empty array at the start of the if statements. Then append the array each time one of the conditions are filled. Then loop through the array and add each element.

```
var x = []
var steps = document.Form.steps.value
if (steps >= 8000) {
   x.push[-1]
}
if (steps >= 6000 && steps < 8000) {
   x.push[-0.5]
}
if (steps >= 4000 && steps < 6000) {
   x.push[0]
}
if (steps >= 2000 && steps < 4000) {
   x.push[1]
}
if (steps >= 1000 && steps < 2000) {
   x.push[1.5]
}
if (steps >= 0 && steps < 1000) {
   x.push[2]
}
if (steps = "") {
   document.form.steps_meaning.value = "error"
  }else  if{
   alert("")
}

sum = 0
for(element in x){
    sum += x
}
```